# Aggregating Data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MachineID   Active_Inactive   Time
    A              0        10.10 am
    A              0        10.11 am
    A              1        10.12 am
    A              0        10.13 am
    A              0        10.14 am
    A              0        10.15 am
    A              1        10.16 am
    A              1        10.17 am
    A              1        10.18 am
```

Now, from the above table I want to find out the output in a way that it gives me how many times Machine **A** was active and how many times inactive in a 2 minute window. So the aggregation needs to be done for every two minute stint. Like **A** was 2- twice inactive from 10.10- 10.11 and 0 times active. How is the best way to represent the output table

There are 5 slots

```
10.10-10.11(1), 10.12-10.13(2) and so on...
```

The output should look something like this..

```
Slots   Active A    Inactive A
  1       0            2
  2       1            1
  3       0            2
  4       1            1
  5       2            0
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your active_inactive time column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I am using Sequel Server

Comment: I dont know sequel server. You can achieve this by joining odd & even rows together

Comment: WHICH DATATYPE YOU ARE USING FOR COLUMN TIME ?????

Comment: Ignore the datatype issue here. I am given a format to make it easier to comprehend as to what I am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that time is a date type, this is the what I would do. Take note that this is on oracle. But it should not differ much.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
  Machine nvarchar2 (10),
  Active number,
  dt date
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 0, to_date('10.10 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 0, to_date('10.11 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 1, to_date('10.12 am', 'hh.mi am'));
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 0, to_date('10.13 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 0, to_date('10.14 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 0, to_date('10.15 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 1, to_date('10.16 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 1, to_date('10.17 am', 'hh.mi am')); 
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', 1, to_date('10.18 am', 'hh.mi am')); 

Select
  Machine, 
  Active, 
  to_char(dt, 'hh') || '.' || to_char(floor(to_char(DT, 'mi') /2) * 2) || '-' || to_char(dt, 'hh') || '.' || to_char(floor(to_char(DT, 'mi') /2) * 2 + 1) timeGroup
from temp
group by Machine, Active, to_char(dt, 'hh') || '.' || to_char(floor(to_char(DT, 'mi') /2) * 2) || '-' || to_char(dt, 'hh') || '.' || to_char(floor(to_char(DT, 'mi') /2) * 2 + 1)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conversion, string and date functions to create grouping

```
SELECT machine_id, active_inactive,CONVERT(VARCHAR(13),time,21)+ ':'+RIGHT ('00'+FLOOR(CAST(DATEPART(minute,time)/2) *2 AS VARCHAR(2)),2), COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY machine_id, active_inactive, CONVERT(VARCHAR(13),time,21)+ ':'+RIGHT ('00'+FLOOR(CAST(DATEPART(minute,time)/2) *2 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```